# I want to create a table and insert a row in same table during run time using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql, dml

I have created a procedure that accepts table name, 2 column names and 2 values that needed to be inserted on create table.

```
create or replace procedure SP_TABLE(P_TAB IN VARCHAR2,P_COL_1 IN VARCHAR2,P_COL_2 VARCHAR2,P_ID IN NUMBER,P_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
AS
v_sql varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||P_TAB||' ('||P_COL_1||' NUMBER, '||P_COL_2 ||' VARCHAR2(20))';
v_sql := 'insert into ' ||P_TAB||'values (:1,:2)'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING P_ID,P_NAME;
END;
/
```

The procedure was successfully created without any errors. However when i ran the below script i got error like 'ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
ORA-06512: at "SQL_PXADYXDREZPVPJSALLEGOZJOB.SP_TABLE", line 7'.

```
DECLARE
V_TAB VARCHAR2(20) := 'TABLE1';
V_COL1 VARCHAR2(20) := 'ID';
V_COL2 VARCHAR2(20) := 'NAME';
V_ID NUMBER := 1;
V_NAME VARCHAR2(20):= 'RAJA';
BEGIN
SP_TABLE(V_TAB,V_COL1,V_COL2,V_ID,V_NAME);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
END;
/
```

some one help me with this.

Comment: Missing space before `values`?

Comment: Arvo thanks a lot..... that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **space** before `values`

```
create or replace procedure SP_TABLE(P_TAB IN VARCHAR2,P_COL_1 IN VARCHAR2,P_COL_2 VARCHAR2,P_ID IN NUMBER,P_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
AS
v_sql varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||P_TAB||' ('||P_COL_1||' NUMBER, '||P_COL_2 ||' VARCHAR2(20))';
v_sql := 'insert into ' ||P_TAB||' values (:1,:2)'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING P_ID,P_NAME;
END;
/
```